# yum groupinstall "Development Tools" - Dependencies Not Found - Centos 6

Tags: git, centos, package, installation, rpm

I'm trying to install Development Tools on Centos 6, but receiving the following errors:

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.12.4-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
       Requires: libneon.so.25()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-perl-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
       Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.15-0.1.el5.rfx.x86_64 (rpmforge-extras)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
       Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           python(abi) = 2.6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have the CentOS 5 rpmforge repository enabled it looks like. Disable it or fix the repo configuration so that it uses the CentOS 6 repository.

Comment: @EtanReisner - noob here, how would I disable the repo?

Comment: Edit the configuration file for it and set `enabled=1` to `enabled=0` (to disable it permanently) or use `yum groupinstall --disablerepo=rpmforge 'Development Tools'` (to disable it just for that one command).